# How to query group in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two table

tblstock

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 20 |
| 2 | ab | 25 |
| 3 | ac | 30 |

tblinputs

| id | name | lot | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 1.01 | 5 |
| 2 | aa | 1.02 | 5 |
| 3 | aa | 2.03 | 10 |
| 4 | ab | 3.04 | 15 |
| 5 | ab | 2.03 | 10 |
| 6 | ac | 1.01 | 10 |
| 7 | ac | 1.04 | 10 |
| 8 | ac | 2.01 | 10 |

how to implement query join and group by on below result

| id | name | lot1 | lot 2 | lot 3 | lot 4 | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 1.01 | 1.02 | 2.03 | 0 | 20 |
| 2 | ab | 3.04 | 2.03 | 0 | 0 | 25 |
| 3 | ac | 1.01 | 2.01 | 1.04 | 0 | 30 |

i has try ,  but not succes

SELECT name, lot  FROM tblinputs INNER JOIN tblitems ON tblitems.id=tblinputs.name GROUP BY lot

Comment: Do a self join on tblinputs

Answer (score 0):

I you can live without the lot1-lot4 headers a group_concat is the simplest way to go

```
SELECT ts.id,ts.name,group_concat(ti.lot order by ti.id) lots,max(ts.stock) qty
from tblstock ts
join tblinputs ti on ti.name = ts.name
group by ts.id,ts.name;
```

if you do need the headers then assign a row_number and conditionally aggregate

```
with cte as(
SELECT ts.id,ts.name,row_number() over(partition  by ts.id order by ti.id) rn,
        ti.lot
from tblstock ts
join tblinputs ti on ti.name = ts.name
),
cte1 as
(select cte.id,cte.name,
        max(case when rn = 1 then cte.lot else 0 end) lot1,
        max(case when rn = 2 then cte.lot else 0 end) lot2,
        max(case when rn = 3 then cte.lot else 0 end) lot3,
        max(case when rn = 4 then cte.lot else 0 end) lot4
from cte
group by cte.id,cte.name
)
select cte1.* , ts.stock
from cte1
join tblstock ts on ts.id = cte1.id;
```

if there can be an unknown, possibly infinite number of lots per id then you need to go dynamic sql

https://dbfiddle.uk/mceDn-Zk